# Asking player to choose whether to load next level

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I am making a ball game, where ball has to reach a specific distance and there he collides with a collider and after that player wins the level. But problem is when player wins level next level comes just after its level ends. I want to ask user after winning the level whether he wants to go to next level or wants to return back to main menu. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? can you share your code?

Comment: You should show your code of collision. There we can help you. Or you can yourself create a boolean variable when the player is inside the collision area. The bool acts like an option to user, if the player sets the bool to true it changes the level or else resumes the same state.

Comment: Make a panel with 3 buttons: Menu, Next, Retry. Disable the panel as default. Show the panel instead of directly loading the next scene when level ends.

Answer (score 1):

What  I understand is that you want your player to be able to either click on a "Go to next level" button or click on a "Back to menu" button.

You need a Canvas, inside of that canvas as a child you will have to create a panel that will be set as inactive by default. Inside that panel you will have to create the two buttons.

Upon the final collision of the level (where you currently switch to the next level) you will have to activate the panel with the buttons.

```
panel.SetActive(true);
```

The two buttons should call (on click) a method that will either start the next level or go back to the main menu. You mentioned that you load the next level when the player reaches the end so I suppose that you know how to load scenes already.

As a bonus you can set `Time.timeScale = 0;` when the player reaches the final destination so that the game "stops" at the end. Set back `Time.timeScale = 1;` when he calls the next scene.

Comment: @DivasrajVimal I'm glad. Also if your problem is solved you can mark the answer so that people know the thread is done. Happy coding!